# Ensime not typechecking correctly, nor is its autocomplete working

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I wanted to try and see how good Ensime's type checking capabilities were, and while they seemed to work fine at first, it appears it keeps referencing bits of code that no longer exist: (larger version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL6zT.png))

[image]

It says it couldn't find the value `asdfadsfasdf` which was correct, back when I wrote it as random garbage to test the type checker; however it's not there anymore and Ensime keeps complaining about it, rather than spotting the missing `:` and wrong type name in the `when` function.

Add to that the fact that despite it having access to the Ensime server, it still won't run autocomplete..

Specs:

- Emacs version: 24.3.1
- Sbt version: 0.13.5
- System: Mac OS X version 10.9.5 "Mavericks"

Excerpt from `.emacs` that relates to Ensime and Scala:

```lisp
(require 'ensime)
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook 'ensime-scala-mode-hook)
```

What do I do to get it working correctly?

Comment: That sbt version should probably be `0.13.5`

Comment: When you say 'keeps complaining about it' have you refreshed the compilation buffer? All `ensime-compilation-result` shows is a 'pretty' version of the compilers output afaik

Comment: yes, refreshing it does nothing, @MrBones

Comment: Regarding the `auto-complete` issue, try adding `(setq ensime-ac-override-settings nil)` to your `.emacs` file.

Comment: @itsjeyd that did absolutely nothing